# SQL Server find duplicates and insert into another table

Tags: sql-server

I have the following procedure into my Database.

```
 begin INSERT INTO
 tblDuplicate(PostingDate,DocumentDate,Reference,URN,Supplier,Amount,St,Check1,Check2,Check3,Check4,Check5,[Source])
 SELECT * FROM (
       SELECT h.PostingDate, h.DocumentDate, h.Reference, h.URN,h.Supplier,h.Amount, h.St,
 h.Check1,h.Check2,h.Check3,h.Check4,h.Check5,h.[Source]
       FROM tblHistory h
       WHERE h.Check1 IN(SELECT Check1 FROM tblTemp)
     UNION 
       SELECT t.PostingDate, t.DocumentDate, t.Reference, t.URN,t.Supplier,t.Amount, t.St,
 t.Check1,t.Check2,t.Check3,t.Check4,t.Check5, t.[Source]
       FROM tblTemp t
       WHERE t.Check1 IN(SELECT Check1 FROM tblHistory)
     ) as AllData   INSERT INTO tblDuplicate(PostingDate,DocumentDate,Reference,URN,Supplier,Amount,St,Check1,Check2,Check3,Check4,Check5,[Source])
 SELECT * FROM (
       SELECT h.PostingDate, h.DocumentDate, h.Reference, h.URN,h.Supplier,h.Amount, h.St,
 h.Check1,h.Check2,h.Check3,h.Check4,h.Check5,h.[Source]
       FROM tblHistory h
       WHERE h.Check2 IN(SELECT Check2 FROM tblTemp)
     UNION 
       SELECT t.PostingDate, t.DocumentDate, t.Reference, t.URN,t.Supplier,t.Amount, t.St,
 t.Check1,t.Check2,t.Check3,t.Check4,t.Check5, t.[Source]
       FROM tblTemp t
       WHERE t.Check2 IN(SELECT Check2 FROM tblHistory)
     ) as AllData INSERT INTO tblDuplicate(PostingDate,DocumentDate,Reference,URN,Supplier,Amount,St,Check1,Check2,Check3,Check4,Check5,[Source])
 SELECT * FROM (
       SELECT h.PostingDate, h.DocumentDate, h.Reference, h.URN,h.Supplier,h.Amount, h.St,
 h.Check1,h.Check2,h.Check3,h.Check4,h.Check5,h.[Source]
       FROM tblHistory h
       WHERE h.Check3 IN(SELECT Check3 FROM tblTemp)
     UNION 
       SELECT t.PostingDate, t.DocumentDate, t.Reference, t.URN,t.Supplier,t.Amount, t.St,
 t.Check1,t.Check2,t.Check3,t.Check4,t.Check5, t.[Source]
       FROM tblTemp t
       WHERE t.Check3 IN(SELECT Check3 FROM tblHistory)
     ) as AllData INSERT INTO tblDuplicate(PostingDate,DocumentDate,Reference,URN,Supplier,Amount,St,Check1,Check2,Check3,Check4,Check5,[Source])
 SELECT * FROM (
       SELECT h.PostingDate, h.DocumentDate, h.Reference, h.URN,h.Supplier,h.Amount, h.St,
 h.Check1,h.Check2,h.Check3,h.Check4,h.Check5,h.[Source]
       FROM tblHistory h
       WHERE h.Check4 IN(SELECT Check4 FROM tblTemp)
     UNION 
       SELECT t.PostingDate, t.DocumentDate, t.Reference, t.URN,t.Supplier,t.Amount, t.St,
 t.Check1,t.Check2,t.Check3,t.Check4,t.Check5, t.[Source]
       FROM tblTemp t
       WHERE t.Check4 IN(SELECT Check4 FROM tblHistory)
     ) as AllData INSERT INTO tblDuplicate(PostingDate,DocumentDate,Reference,URN,Supplier,Amount,St,Check1,Check2,Check3,Check4,Check5,[Source])
 SELECT * FROM (
       SELECT h.PostingDate, h.DocumentDate, h.Reference, h.URN,h.Supplier,h.Amount, h.St,
 h.Check1,h.Check2,h.Check3,h.Check4,h.Check5,h.[Source]
       FROM tblHistory h
       WHERE h.Check5 IN(SELECT Check5 FROM tblTemp)
     UNION 
       SELECT t.PostingDate, t.DocumentDate, t.Reference, t.URN,t.Supplier,t.Amount, t.St,
 t.Check1,t.Check2,t.Check3,t.Check4,t.Check5, t.[Source]
       FROM tblTemp t
       WHERE t.Check5 IN(SELECT Check5 FROM tblHistory)
     ) as AllData end
```

The procedure above mostly checks if check 1 to check 5 is duplicate and then send both records into tblDuplicate.

Is there any solution where i can simplify the above procedure please.

table is as below

```
PostingDate  DocumentDate Reference URN   Supplier  St   Check1
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
2018-10-05    12/09/2018   12345    12345   12345    2   12/09/201812345
```

All tables contains the same columns.

procedure is expected to find duplicates of check1,check2,check3.check4.check5 and then insert the results into tblDuplicate.

stored proc for check1 , check2, check3 check 4 and check 5 is as below:

```
begin
UPDATE tblHistory SET Check1 = Supplier+Reference;
update tblHistory set Check2 = Supplier + DocumentDate + str(Amount,7,2) ;
update tblHistory set Check3 = Supplier + Reference + str(Amount,7,2);
update tblHistory set Check4 = Supplier +  DocumentDate + Reference + str(Amount,7,2);
update tblHistory set Check5 = DocumentDate + str(Amount,7,2) + Reference;
end
```

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Where is `check2`, `check3`, `check4`, and `check5` in your one line of sampled data?

Comment: check 1,2,3,4,5 is given by another stored procedure which concatenate the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO tblDuplicate(PostingDate,DocumentDate,Reference,URN,Supplier,Amount,St,Check1,Check2,Check3,Check4,Check5,[Source])
    SELECT
        PostingDate,DocumentDate,Reference,URN,Supplier,Amount,St,Check1,Check2,Check3,Check4,Check5,[Source]
    FROM (
        SELECT h.PostingDate, h.DocumentDate, h.Reference, h.URN,h.Supplier,h.Amount, h.St,h.Check1,h.Check2,h.Check3,h.Check4,h.Check5,h.[Source]
        FROM tblHistory h
        INNER JOIN tblTemp tmp ON tmp.Check1=h.Check1
            OR tmp.Check2=h.Check2
            OR tmp.Check3=h.Check3
            OR tmp.Check4=h.Check4
            OR tmp.Check5=h.Check5
        UNION ALL
        SELECT h.PostingDate, h.DocumentDate, h.Reference, h.URN,h.Supplier,h.Amount, h.St,h.Check1,h.Check2,h.Check3,h.Check4,h.Check5,h.[Source]
        FROM tblTemp h
        INNER JOIN tblTemp tmp ON tmp.Check1=h.Check1
            OR tmp.Check2=h.Check2
            OR tmp.Check3=h.Check3
            OR tmp.Check4=h.Check4
            OR tmp.Check5=h.Check5
    ) AS AllData
```

Comment: after running the query. only one record was returned. what i needed is that two record are returned. one from tblTemp and one from tblHistory. Thanks

Comment: @yovenkali sample data please

Comment: @yovenkali try again, I changed the union to a union all.